# Rotate an image by 90 degree clockwise

Tags: c++

I'm trying to rotate an image pixel by pixel by 90 degrees, It seems there is a math problem that I couldn't figure out...and array out of bounds exception
here is my attempt

```
const unsigned char *srcData = source.getData();
unsigned char *dstData = new unsigned char[width * height * bpp];


 size_t srcPitch = source.getRowSpan();
    size_t dstPitch = width * bpp;

     for(int i=0; i<height; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<width * bpp; j++)
        {
            rotatedData[(i * dstPitch) + j]= dstData[(height-i) * dstPitch + j];
        }
    }
```

Comment: `*` has higher precendence than `-` (same in maths and C++)

Comment: still has some bounds dstData[i+j*width*bpp] = srcData[(width * bpp)*j +  1 - j];

Comment: You already have dstPitch, not sure why you aren't using that in your condition for the inner for loop.

Comment: @tobi303 Can you post a fix as answer

Comment: I still can't rotate the image, seems the math is incorrect

Comment: @Eddge edited my question

Comment: @ahmedandre thanks but what is `source`?  what type is it? what is the format of your image? is every index a single pixel? in `srcData`

Comment: yes every index is a single pixel

Comment: Alright so what is `bpp` for then?

Comment: @Eddge bytes per pixel

Comment: I would like to rotate the image 90 degree clockwise

Comment: Alright so if every single index is a pixel, then there really isn't a need for `bpp` is there?  because how many bytes is a char?  if every single index in your data is a pixel that means you are allotting 1 `unsigned char` per pixel, aka 1 byte.

Comment: What I am trying to point out is, based off of what I am reading, I don't believe every index is a single pixel, because of `bpp`, it maybe part of a pixel.  if you have 4 bytes per pixel, and each byte represents `red`, `green`, `blue`, `alpha`  then every index could be one those colors per pixel.

Comment: @Eddge You are correct every pixel is 4 components

Comment: What I want to achieve is to rotate the image -90 degrees

Comment: @ahmedandre I can't really give you a 100% answer on how to fix your issue, as I cannot reproduce it with the code you have provided, but I can tell you, that 1 of your issues is with this part of your code: `dstData[i+j*width*bpp]` j will index every value from 0 -> `width * bpp`, and then you are scaling that value again... so (last iteration j is width*bpp-1) you are then scaling it again.

Comment: That's the third time you've told us that; repeating it doesn't help. Please edit into your question _exactly_ how the bits/bytes/pixels are laid out; both beforehand and how you want them afterwards. In addition to what Eddge notes, your indexing into `srcData[]` features **no** use of multiply (`*`): _something_ should be multiplied by some expression of either `i` or `j`.

Comment: I have edited the post. Basically each pixel has 4 bytes RGBA, so I want  to rotate it by -90 degrees.

Comment: @TripeHound I have fixed it but the image is flipped not rotated, please see the updated post

Comment: `rotatedData ... = dstData ...` what?

Comment: Unless `width == height`, you need a different pitch for the rotated image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's build an image descriptor to keep track of the dimensions.

```
struct ImageDescriptor {
  std::size_t width;
  std::size_t height;
  std::size_t channels;

  std::size_t stride() const { return width * channels; }
  std::size_t offset(std::size_t row, std::size_t col, std::size_t chan) {
    assert(0 <= row && row < height);
    assert(0 <= col && col < width);
    assert(0 <= chan && chan < channels);
    return row*stride() + col*channels + chan;
    // or, depending on your coordinate system ...
    // return (height - row - 1)*stride() + col*channels + chan;
  }
  std::size_t size() const { return height * stride(); }
};
```

Now we'll need two ImageDescriptors to keep track of the dimensions of our two images.  Note that, unless the original image is square, the rotated image will have a different width and height (and thus stride).  Specifically, the width of the rotated image will be the height of the source image (and vice versa).

```
const ImageDescriptor source(width, height, bpp);
ImageDescriptor target(height, width, bpp);  // note width/height swap
```

A common way to do a transformation is to loop over the destination pixels and look up the source pixels.

```
unsigned char *rotated = new[target.size()];

for (std::size_t row = 0; row < target.height; ++row) {
  for (std::size_t col = 0; col < target.width; ++col) {
    for (std::size_t chan = 0; chan < target.channels; ++chan) {
       rotated[target.offset(row, col, chan)] =
           original[source.offset(col, row, chan)];
    }
  }
}
```

Once you get it right, you can work to eliminate unnecessary computation.  The first opportunity is to just step our way through the destination image, since all that is in memory order.  The second opportunity is, to hoist the source offset calculation out of the channel loop.  Finally, if bpp is a constant, you can unroll the innermost loop.

```
unsigned char *p = rotated;
for (std::size_t row = 0; row < target.height; ++row) {
  for (std::size_t col = 0; col < target.width; ++col) {
    const std::size_t base = source.offset(col, row, 0);
    for (std::size_t chan = 0; chan < target.channels; ++chan) {
       *p++ = original[base + chan];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that great answer. But I still get scanlined image

Comment: @ahmed andre: I don't know what you mean by "scanlined image".

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
   for (int j = 0; j<width * bpp; j++)
    {
       for (int i = 0 ; i<height; i++)
        {
          rotatedData[(height)*(dstPitch - j - 1) + i] = dstData[(i * dstPitch) + j];
        }
    }
```

and if dstData isn't squared:

```
//define rotatedData_height before.
    rotatedData[(rotatedData_height)*(dstPitch - j - 1) + i] = dstData[(i * dstPitch) + j];
```

Comment: I tried it but I get scanlines.. seems its not working correctly

Comment: can you show how do you iterate over the for loops ?

Comment: @ahmedandre added the for loops.

Comment: still scanlines

Comment: What are the width and height of dstData?

Comment: @ahmed andre If the height of dstData is not equal to it's width use it in this way :   rotatedData[(rotatedData_height)*(dstPitch - j - 1) + i] = dstData[(i * dstPitch) + j];